# Trapping region for Nonlinear ODE system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a trapping region for

$u'=-u+vu^2$

$ v'=b-vu^2$

with $b>0$.

I don't know what theory to use or in wich book I can find some examples to find optimal trapping regions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Finding a trapping region when $b<1$ might not be an easy task...

Comment: But I need when b>0, because i know that b>0

Comment: This may be so. But as I said, you will not find a trapping region when 0<b<1.

Comment: @Did May I know what's your reasoning behind this?

Comment: @Evgeny Simulations of phase diagrams for various values of b plus mathematical study of the local behaviour near the fixed point.

Comment: @Did Well, we definitely do the same things, but come to different conclusions :)

Comment: @Evgeny Maybe I made a mistake--but what are your conclusions?

Comment: @Did The equilibrium point is at $(\frac{1}{b}, b)$ and Jacobian of system is $\left \lbrack \begin{array}{cc} 1 & b^2 \\ -2 & -b^2 \end{array} \right \rbrack$ at it. For $ -1 + \sqrt{2} < b < 1 + \sqrt{2}$ system has complex eigenvalues. At $b = 1$ happens an Andronov-Hopf bifurcation: stable limit cycle collides with unstable focus and focus becomes stable. So my concern is that for $b < 1$ there is a stable limit cycle, which always has a trapping region (though it's not simple to define by formulas).

Comment: @Evgeny When the eigenvalues have a nonzero complex part, their common real part (half the trace) indicates the stability of the fixed point. For b<1, it is positive, hence the fixed point is an unstable focus or an unstable node. You seem to be saying that for some initial condition near the fixed point, the solution stays bounded. As I said, I looked at the system only near its fixed point, however, my impression is that the solutions starting near the fixed point do spiral outward, staying confined to the positive quadrant, but being unbounded. Why do you think there is a cycle when b<1?

Comment: @Did So for $0 < b < 1$ we have unstable focus, at $b = 1$ we have purely imaginary eigenvalues and for $ 1 < b < 1 + \sqrt{2}$ equilibrium is stable focus. My reasoning is that we likely to hit codimension 1 bifurcation in one-parameter family than anything else. And this suits Andronov-Hopf bifurcation pretty well: the equilibrium loses its stability through birth of stable limit cycle (of course if we first consider $b > 1$, then $b =1$ and then $b < 1$).

Comment: @Evgeny Hmmm... So you do not know. :-)

Comment: @Did In what sense and what exactly I don't know? :)

Comment: @Evgeny Whether there is actually a cycle when b<1, or not. Or did I misunderstand what you were saying?

Comment: @Did I think you've slightly misunderstood me. From bifurcation theory point of view I'm sure that there's a limit cycle for $ 0 < b < 1$. If we increase parameter $b$ from values less than one to values greater than one, we hit a bifurcation at $b = 1$. Because equilibrium has complex eigenvalues and changes stability during this variation of parameter, we can deduce that Andronov-Hopf bifurcation happened  and the stability of equilibrium is acquired through colliding of stable limit cycle with unstable focus. I'm trying to find this cycle numerically at this moment.

Comment: @Evgeny "From bifurcation theory point of view I'm sure that there's a limit cycle for 0<b<1" Indeed this is the part I do not understand (and, unless I am mistaken, which is not proven in your comments).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26263/discussion-between-evgeny-and-did).

Comment: Sorry I do not chat. But please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Okay :) so, what exactly you don't understand? Is your question why limit cycle persists for all values $b \in (0, 1)$? Or why does its existence follow from Andronov-Hopf bifurcation?

Comment: Speaking about numerical simulation I can say that it's very hard to find this limit cycle because it very quickly approaches $Oy$ axis which is flow invariant and tends to "attract" numeric trajectories. See my simulations here: https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/6d1d7f14-0203-4836-8256-10282cc792b8/files/trapping_region.sagews

Comment: Indeed I was asking for a proof of the existence of a cycle. Thanks for the simulations, which seem pretty convincing.

Comment: When we analyze eigenvalues of Jacobi matrix we see that passing through $b = 1$ changes stability of equilbrium and eigenvalues pass through pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues (it's not structurally stable case). This is what typically indicates that Andronov-Hopf bifurcation happened: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation . It has been proven by other people that in such situations there are two generic scenarios and both of them involve the birth of limit cycle. In non-generic scenarios more cycles could be born, but at least one is presented.

Comment: So the conclution is that while $0<b<b*$  and $b*\in(0.9,1)$ or something like that there is a limit cycle?.

Comment: So whats is the step by step I should follow to find and conclude that there's a limit cycle and for wich values of b i should do that prove?. It is neccesary and I do not know how to do those steps. Please Help me. I've beeing readind all these comments but I can't still figure it out. @Evgengy

Comment: So whats is the step by step I should follow to find and conclude that there's a limit cycle and for wich values of b i should do that prove?. It is neccesary and I do not know how to do those steps. Please Help me. I've beeing readind all these comments but I can't still figure it out. @Did

Comment: @Evgeny can I get your packages from the simulation aboves plis... in order to run the complete programm and get the graphics PLEASE?

Comment: @Evgeny I've beeing traying to find the trapping region but I think I'll keep the simulations you presented above as true because it is very diffucult to find that trapping region. Would you mind to give me a kind of "step by step" of the suggestions in order to find it out please, or at least provided me your packages and libraries from you python program to see and make by myself those simulations PLEASE?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your messages (because you've made a typo in my nickname). You can see all Python imports in top cell of SAGE worksheet. The only thing that you won't find in Python packages is my little workaround for plotting vector fields; you can find it here https://gist.github.com/Evgenij-Gr/bcf24b826d830da06b65 .

Comment: @Evgeny sorry I bother you but I'm totally newbie in python where I have to put those libraries and how... I know maybe sound so stupid but I want to visualice those graphs and I can't do it by myself and I tried to do those simulations on MATHEMATICA but the graphic proccesor looks so accuared and shows the graphics pretty bad.

Comment: If you want to do this super fast I think you'd better just register at Sage Math Cloud, create an empty Sage worksheet and just copy&paste the content of my worksheet. It'll be a bit lengthier to explain how to set up Python environment locally.

Comment: @Evgeny i do that but now i get this message... in Sage

Error in lines 1-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/f87dddff-3b65-464c-951a-4ffa2d9093da/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py", line 879, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named np_plots

Comment: Ah. Push the "Download ZIP" button at the gist page and put np_plots.py in the same folder where is your SAGE worksheet.

Comment: @Evgeny sorry to keep bothering you but it keep showing me the same error

Comment: That's weird. If you have put the file near the worksheet it should see it already. Push the "Restart" button of worksheet, I think it should help. If it won't -- I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Thank you very much @Evgeny it work pretty cool and now I can move on onn my reasear about the glycolysis and all thanks to you... How can I put a star o a qualyfication for you?

Comment: You're welcome :) don't worry about that, since I haven't answered your initial question. Frankly speaking, I almost have no idea how to analytically find a trapping region for this system. Since we have a stable limit cycle for all $b \in (0, 1)$ this trapping region exists (because stable limit cycle has its attracting neighbourhood), but I don't have idea what formulas can provide numerical evidence for its existence.

Comment: @ Evgeny My thesis director told me that maybe Green's theorem should it work but I can't figure it out how to do it since Green's theorem just find the area under some conditions or regions and for a trapping region we need some other conditions as the divergence or something like that. Wich I don't understand is whats you were discussing with @Did for the values of the eigenvalues and beeing atacking the problem for this side but I can't catch that damn trapping region, and I've beeing looking in some other texts and ther is nothing like that.

Comment: @Evgeny hey do you have any idea of how to demonstrate the existence of this $b*=0.90016$. I mean, you simulations are obviously very convincent but Do you think is there a way to prove the upper bound of 

$b*<b<1$?

Comment: Well, this $b^\ast$ occured because numerical integration has its own quirks. There's an explanation above why we don't see this limit cycle after some value of parameter. In my opinion this limit cycle exists for all $b \in (0, 1) $.

Comment: I've got a little idea and a little question. **An idea** I've (re)discovered Sum-of-Squares decomposition of polynomials. You might try your luck and do the following. Because you have polynomial vector field, you might try find poly $F(x,y)$ s.t. $F(x,y) = 0$ is bounded level set, the equilibrium point is inside and vector field points inward along $F(x,y)$ (it's equivalent to $(\nabla F(x,y), V(x,y) )$ having constant sign; the concrete sign depends on what value has $F(x,y)$ at equilibrium). The constant sign condition is hard task for polynomials, but you might try to find $F(x,y)$....

Comment: .... such that $(\nabla F(x,y), V(x,y) )$ is a Sum-of-Squares polynomial. This is computationally feasible. I guarantee nothing, but this looks like a solid (but not necessarily fruitful) approach. **A question** What was the idea of your scientific advisor about Green's theorem?

Comment: @Evgeny the Green's theorem was a first aproximation idea because it says all about the vector field going inward or at least at any direction we want, in this case we want the Green's theorem point inward. I can't figure it out what you're sayin with $\nabla F(x,y)$ it means the gradient of $(u,v)$ and $V(u,v)$ means...?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Well, I don't know why he calls it this way, but we have the same idea: vector field must point inward along some closed curve which encloses equilibrium. To my comment: sorry, I messed up the notation. $V(u, v)$ means a vector field that defines your system of ODEs, i.e. $V(u, v) = (-u+vu^2, b-vu^2)$. The $F(u, v)$ means some yet unknown polynomial function of $u$ and $v$; the $\nabla F$ is just $(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}) $.

Comment: @Did the equilibrium point is right?. My calculations gave me $(b,1/b)$ so it is kind of different. That changes all the Jacobian matrix evaluated in the equilibrium point.

Comment: @Evgeny I was checking all the calculations before and as you'll see I got a differente equlibrium point, wich means that the jacobian matrix will change all its values right? I got $(b,1/b)$

Comment: @IvanGarcia It's not a rocket science to check whether Jacobi matrix changed after that or not :) I checked my calculations: I wrote wrong coordinates for equilibria, but matrix has been written right.

Comment: @IvanGarcia I suggest you to skim the beginning of this article: http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4421 . This should pretty explain my idea about finding polynomial Lyapunov function using Sum-of-Squares polynomial.

Comment: The most important part is 2.1 (Non-negativity witness). This is what you need to show that some polynomial would be non-zero along some level set of another polynomial function. My guts feeling tells me that it is still computationally feasible. But I'm not 100% sure :)